# Test if include/import has been already done

Tags: julia

I have the following include/import in my "main.jl" file:

```
include("Global.jl")
import .Global
```

As importing this module takes some time and it is always the same on every execution, I would like test in advance if .Global exists so I can bypass the include/import.

The idea is that I can edit all changes in my text editor and use the interactive console to reload the whole program but waiving that step if it is already there.

Comment: Try the "package-centric" workflow described at https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/cookbook/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isdefined(Main, :ModuleName)` (don't forget the colon).

```
if !isdefined(Main, :Global)
    include("Global.jl")
    import .Global
end
```

For the same question when you are `using` a package named "MyPackage":

```
if !isdefined(Main, :MyPackage)
    using MyPackage
end
```

Answer (score 5):

`import X` is already basically a no-op if `X` has already been imported.
The problem is when you do the `include` you are defining a new module also called `X` so `import` tries and loads the new one.

I suggest thus converting your module into a package, 
adding it to your environment, then just doing `import X`